# jquery lightbox recognising text links as an image inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, lightbox

I am using jquery lightbox and I have one div with a lightbox function on it. Inside this div i have another div which has a text link. The jquery is recognising the text link as an image and trying to open it as such and ignoring the link to the other page. Below is the html for the div.

```
**<div id="royalartcontent">

   <p><b> The Royal Artillery<br>
      <br>
      </b><strong>19th Regiment Royal Artillery, The Highland Gunners</strong>  </p>
   <p>    <a href="images/19reg.jpg"><img src="images/19regsm.jpg" alt="19th Regiment Royal Artillery, The Highland Gunners" width="126" height="142" border="1"></a>
    19th Regiment Royal Artillery, The Highland Gunners, currently supports 12 Mechanised Brigade in the armoured field artillery role. The regiment has Fire Support Teams mounted in Warrior Mechanised Artillery Observation Vehicles equipped with MSTAR. The regiment&rsquo;s three gun batteries are equipped with 18 AS-90 self-propelled guns.

  </p>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>5 (Gibraltar 1779&ndash;1783) Battery<br>
     13 (Martinique 1809) Headquarters Battery<br>
     28/143 (Tombs&rsquo;s Troop) Battery<br>
     52 (Niagara) Battery<br>
     127 (Dragon) Battery</p>
   <p>19th Regiment is based in Tidworth, Wiltshire. They recruit from Highlands, Grampian, Tayside, Fife, Central and Argyle.</p>
   <p>19 Regiment RA is the local Artillery Regiment of the Highland areas of Scotland, The Western Islands, The Shetland Islands and The Orkney Islands. The Regiment has been granted the Freedom of the Cities of Inverness and Colchester and wears the Robertson Hunting tartan of the Clan Donnachaidh.<br>
     Freedom of the City<br>
     Taken from: wikipedia.org/wiki/19th_Regiment_Royal_Artillery</p>
   <p><div id="royalart"><a href="images/Guns.jpg"><img src="images/Gunssm.jpg" alt="Guns firing at Edinburgh Castle" width="170" height="112" border="1"></a></div>
   <div class="royalart1"><a href="105threg.html">105th Regiment Royal Artillery (Volunteers)</a></div>**
```

The main div is the "royalartcontent" div and the one containing the text link is "royalart1". I have only copied a portion of the div as there is other content below this.

I have a div within a div because the full content is too long for the page so I am using overflow:auto on the "royalartcontent" div. Otherwise I wouldn't put a div inside other divs.

Anyone got an ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a http://jsfiddle.com where you demonstrate the problem and perhaps also make the problem you are facing a bit clearer?

Comment: @JonasG.Drange
Here is the link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/esRFt/9/

I have altered some of the div names from above but nothing major...